# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqile.SQliteConnection' threw an exception C#

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Library e_sqlite3 not found
   at SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.Load(String libraryName, Assembly assy, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.MakeDynamic(String name, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.DoDynamic_cdecl(String name, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace
```

I got this message when i create a setup file of my project when i execute the application.
But when i debug it in visual studio it is working well and have not any issue.

Comment: Hello Jafar, Please make sure your your setup can copy all the dependencies to your application path. As exception detail says e_sqlite library missing on your application path I guess.

Comment: yes some files did not copy when i create the setup file Thanks for your answer

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19396. By this link, you can find few solutions.

Comment: ok ty, the issue was in my connection string

Comment: first i got my application directory name and my data base was in there ,then add my db name and directory together in a string variable and then set it to connection string of my db